Remove duplicate lines based on specific string
I try to remove duplicate lines based on specific string. There is two similar cases in my question.
I have this kind of file:
20151222051106 http://website.org/2015-12-11-art1
20151222054115 http://website.org/2015-12-11-art1
20151222054123 http://website.org/2015-12-11-art1
20151222050165 http://website.org/2015-12-12-art2
20151222051901 http://website.org/2015-12-12-art3
20151222051120 http://website.org/2015-12-14-art4
20151222051125 http://website.org:80/2015-12-14-art4
20151222051133 https://website.org/2015-12-14-art4

First, I would like to remove lines (while keeping the first one) with the same url.
This would be the result:
20151222051106 http://website.org/2015-12-11-art1
20151222050165 http://website.org/2015-12-12-art2
20151222051901 http://website.org/2015-12-12-art3
20151222051120 http://website.org/2015-12-14-art4
20151222051125 http://website.org:80/2015-12-14-art4
20151222051133 https://website.org/2015-12-14-art4

Secondly, would like to remove duplicate lines (while keeping the first one) based on specific parts of the url string.
Based on the results of the first question. When several URLs are the same except for the "http" or "https" part. I would like to keep only the first line.
20151222051106 http://website.org/2015-12-11-art1
20151222050165 http://website.org/2015-12-12-art2
20151222051901 http://website.org/2015-12-12-art3
20151222051120 http://website.org/2015-12-14-art4
20151222051125 http://website.org:80/2015-12-14-art4

I ask both in the same post because it's basicaly the same question (and I think both can probably be done using sed).

sed? no. awk? yes.
The first one can be answered with
awk '!seen[$2]++' file

20151222051106 http://website.org/2015-12-11-art1
20151222050165 http://website.org/2015-12-12-art2
20151222051901 http://website.org/2015-12-12-art3
20151222051120 http://website.org/2015-12-14-art4
20151222051125 http://website.org:80/2015-12-14-art4
20151222051133 https://website.org/2015-12-14-art4

This is a "famous" awk idiom: filtering on the 2nd field ($2), print the line only the first time it is seen. I'll point you to the stackoverflow awk info page for details.

For the second part, we need to refine what's stored as the array key: instead of $2 (the whole URL) we need to normalize the scheme:
awk '
    {key = $2; sub(/^https/, "http", key)}
    !seen[key]++
' file


Thank you. I've edited the second question, I understand why it is confusing.
